# Problem Publishing WCF Ria Application Over Citrix Access Gateway

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, citrix

We currently have a silverlight app, one that uses "vanilla" wcf services and one that uses WCF Ria Services.

We publish the application via a citrix access gateway (secure web proxy).

The SL app that accesses the WCF Service works fine, but the RIA one fails with a ton of "response invalid" errors.

If you browse to the service url of either service (using the citrix url), then you see the WCF Service description fine.

Does anyone have any idea of any special config needed to enable WCF RIA Service apps to work over a Citrix Access Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the endpoint of the WCF RIA client proxy? Because I suspect it is trying to go to `http://your.website.com/yourApp/yourService.svc` when it really needs to go to `http://your.website.com/cvpn/BIG_HASH_HERE/yourApp/yourService.svc`. I have had to jump through some hoops to explicitly support the Citrix Access Gateway in a Silverlight app that I am working on at the moment (will come back later and possibly elucidate further when I have reviewed the code).

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll have a look...its a third part app but I am in touch with the devs.... will use Fiddler to see what it's calling....